# Cannot load WEB-INF from browser

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I start test my app with primefaces and spring integration but I stop on `p:commandButton` component. When I click on it, I want show p:growl popup component like [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml), but unfortunately page is redirect to view in location `/WEB-INF/WEB-INF/intro.xhtml` (but view is located in `/WEB-INF/intro.xhtml`) with error of 'resource not found'. May be some one know the problem? I download some example [project](https://github.com/acichon89/springmvcfacelets.git) from GIT and then get the same problem. I change some view code in

> /springmvcfacelets/src/main/webapp/templates/maintemplate.xhtml

and paste code from primefaces

```
<h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />

<p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" id="ajax" update="growl" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

<p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" id="nonAjax" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" ajax="false" />

<p:commandButton value="With Icon" id="withIcon" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" update="growl" icon="ui-icon-disk" />

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" id="iconOnly" update="growl" icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Icon Only" />

<p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="disabled" disabled="true" />
```

to body in view. Bean was also added and registered.
View code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
 <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
 <h:form>
  <p:panel id="panel" header="New User">
   <h:form>
    <p:growl id="growl" life="2000" />

    <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" id="ajax" update="growl"
     actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}"
     styleClass="ui-priority-primary" />

    <p:commandButton value="Non-Ajax Submit" id="nonAjax"
     actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" ajax="false" />

    <p:commandButton value="With Icon" id="withIcon"
     actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" update="growl"
     icon="ui-icon-disk" />

    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}"
     id="iconOnly" update="growl" icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Icon Only" />

    <p:commandButton value="Disabled" id="disabled" disabled="true" />
   </h:form>
  </p:panel>
 </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your commandButton code and your Growl component.

Comment: The comment above is incomplete. Please read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and act accordingly (we are not clairvoyant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in web.xml(missing appropriate path for JSF) file and in code of the view.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with primefaces neither the commandbutton component.
You simply can't access files located in the WEB-INF directory using browser. It would be security bug. Web-Inf would be good for loading integrated tempates using `<ui:include>` (for example) or for storing your configuration (`faces-config.xml`, `web.xml`, `app-context.xml` ...).

Move your file to any other webapp directory excluding web-inf and change the submit result (where page goes, either from form action or from bean) and let us know the result.

Comment: Yes You have right, I put the view file in wrong directory.. I corrected this but the problem still appeared. In the end I had found the solution -> I added in web.xml appropriate mapper path and the second part was in the view file code. :) Now everything working correctly